# Is it possible to create and execute 2 triggers on one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find some workaround to create and execute multiple triggers for different tables on one table. I have 2 tables

- Person Detail
- Address

The way this table is designed is when a user updates Person's address it creates a new record into address table instead of updating the existing one and I want to insert the changes into auditlog table when a user updates person details or address.

I was able to create a trigger for person table but dont know how can i make it work by using or calling multiple triggers on Person Table

Following is the code for Person table update trigger

```
 CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_tblPersonDetail_ForUpdate]
 ON  [dbo].[PersonDetail]
 FOR Update
AS 
BEGIN
Declare @Id int,                          
Declare @OldFirstName varchar(50), @NewFirstName varchar(50)

BEGIN

     Select @Id=personId,@NewFirstName = NewFirstName from Inserted

     select @OldFirstName = NewFirstName from deleted where @id = personId

  if(@OldFirstName <> @NewFirstName )
  Insert into AuditLog values('some value','AfterValue','Before Value')
```

Comment: Doesn't answer your question but keep in mind that `inserted` and `deleted` can have more than 1 row

Comment: I would recommend to not use triggers. Do it in a stored procedure instead. If you need to manually update any of these tables, you or anyone else working on this needs to remember to disable the triggers.

Comment: Yes you can make as many triggers as you want on the same table. That is not a problem at all. But the code in your example will fail because `Inserted`is a table that can hold more than one row

Comment: why not just have two inserts instead of using two triggers? or you can consider using `MERGE JOIN`

Comment: @dfundako Allthough I agree that triggers should not be used to much, there is no reason to disable them when updating the table. Triggers can be used without problems for logging and when to use them or not depends on the situation which we do not know in this case

Comment: Why would you ask if it's possible to create two triggers on the same table?   Are you not allowed to try without first finding out from someone else if it's possible?

Comment: Why do you need multiple triggers on one table?  I am missing the use-case.  You seem to want two triggers on two different tables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one table may have multiple triggers. You do need to exercise caution, however - you may not want every update to fire both triggers, or you may have need to execute the triggers in a particular order.

It really sounds like you want an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger for the requirement of

> creates a new record into address table instead of updating the existing one

If you need your trigger to execute only if specific field(s) were updated, use [`UPDATED()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to test for them.

You can use [`sp_settriggerorder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-settriggerorder-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to dictate which trigger should execute and which one last.

In your case, I would suggest an `AFTER UPDATE` for any operation that changes only the person's name, and then an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` which handles cases where the address is changed (which will also need to handle the name change).

If you choose to continue down the path of using triggers at all.

Comment: I got your point what you saying but what if i have 30 columns in a person table and if i dont to check each coloumns for update. Is there any other way that i dont have to check each column ?